# Oracle DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_TUNING_TASK returns errors section with ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle

I am trying to generate a SQL query tuning report.  Given an SQL ID (`$sql_id`), I tried:

```
SELECT DBMS_SQLTUNE.CREATE_TUNING_TASK(sql_id => '$sql_id', time_limit => 500) FROM DUAL
```

Then, use the output, e.g., `TASK_935`, in query #2 & #3:

```
SELECT DBMS_SQLTUNE.EXECUTE_TUNING_TASK(task_name => 'TASK_#') FROM DUAL
SELECT DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_TUNING_TASK('TASK_#') FROM DUAL
```

Query #3 returns an incomplete report.  It looks like this (abbreviated with ...):

```
GENERAL INFORMATION SECTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tuning Task Name   : TASK_935
...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERRORS SECTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't know what permissions are missing.  To be clear, I *can* run these three queries on some other databases where I have access.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_AUTO_SQLTUNE.html#GUID-ADF2CE53-4E0D-4EA3-A3B6-DCC224517A29) for DBMS_SQLTUNE:

> 29.2 DBMS_AUTO_SQLTUNE Security Model
>
> **This package is available to users with the DBA role. For other users, you must grant the EXECUTE
> privilege on the package explicitly.** Note that the
> EXECUTE_AUTO_TUNING_TASK procedure is an exception: only SYS can
> invoke it.
>
> Users can call APIs in this package to control how the automatic
> tuning task behaves when it runs, such as enabling automatic SQL
> profile creation and configuring the total and per-SQL time limits
> under which the task runs. Because these settings affect the overall
> performance of the database, it may not be appropriate for all users
> with the ADVISOR privilege to have access to this package.

You need to have a conversation with your DBA to determine what you're missing and what is appropriate for your particular situation: whether you should have the `DBA` role or explicit `EXECUTE` privileges on the package.